Optimized function to read and format Excel files in Databricks
I wrote a small function to read data from CSV files and store the output in formatted Excel workbooks. The code will be run in an Azure Databricks notebook running on a spark cluster. How should I go about optimising this function?

!pip install xlsxwriter --quiet --disable-pip-version-check

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import xlsxwriter

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, round, to_date

from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType, DateType, TimestampType

import shutil



def check_lists_length(*lists): 

  return not(all(len(lst) == len(lists[0]) for lst in lists)) 



def client_file_creator_from_csv(sheet_names, table_names, file_names, csv_list, output_path): 

  """

  Reads a list of CSV files and returns formatted Excel Workbooks in Azure Databricks

  

  Parameters:

  sheet_names (list): A list of strings representing worksheet names of the final workbooks

  table_names (list): A list of strings representing table headers of the final workbooks

  file_names (list): A list of strings representing file names for the final workbooks

  csv_list (list): A list of strings representing the input paths of the CSV files

  output_path (string) : A string representing the output path for the Excel workbooks

  """

  if check_lists_length(sheet_names, table_names, file_names, csv_list):

    raise Exception("The number of CSV files and file names and sheet names and table names must be the same")



  #Convert CSV file paths to dbfs format for use with dbutils and pyspark

  csv_list = ["dbfs:" + str.split(x,"dbfs")[1] for x in csv_list]

  #Convert output file paths to dbfs format for use with dbutils and pyspark

  path_api = "dbfs:" + str.split(output_path,"dbfs")[1]

  #Create output path in case it doesn't exist

  dbutils.fs.mkdirs(path_api)

  #Create temporary path in dbfs to store ExcelWriter objects

  temp_path = "/tmp/" + str.split(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().userName().get(), sep = '@')[0]

  #Create lists to store pandas dataframes and ExcelWriter objects

  dfs = list()

  writers = list()

  for i,csv in enumerate(csv_list):

    df = spark.read.option("header", True).option("nullValue", "null").option("delimiter", ",").option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"").option("multiLine", True).option("inferSchema", True).option("enforceSchema", True).option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").csv(csv)

    if df.count() == 0:

      raise Exception('File does not have any rows') 

    dcml_cols = [f.name for f in df.schema.fields if isinstance(f.dataType, DecimalType)]

    time_cols = [f.name for f in df.schema.fields if isinstance(f.dataType, TimestampType)]

    for col_name in dcml_cols:

      df = df.withColumn(col_name, round(col(col_name).cast('double'),2))

    for col_name in time_cols:

      df = df.withColumn(col_name, to_date(col(col_name)))

    dfs.append(df.select("*").toPandas())

    writers.append(pd.ExcelWriter(f"{temp_path}_{i}.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter"))



  for df, writer, sheet_name, table_name, file_name in zip(dfs,writers, sheet_names, table_names, file_names):

    #Since Excel has a row limit of 1,048,576 rows per worksheet, larger dataframes must be split across multiple worksheets

    split_df = np.array_split(df,(df.shape[0]//1000000)+1)

    workbook = writer.book

    #Add standard formatting as required

    top_border = workbook.add_format({'top': 2})

    bottom_border = workbook.add_format({'bottom': 2})

    left_border = workbook.add_format({'left': 2})

    right_border = workbook.add_format({'right': 2})

    top_left_border = workbook.add_format({'top': 2, 'left': 2})

    top_right_border = workbook.add_format({'top': 2, 'right': 2})

    bottom_left_border = workbook.add_format({'bottom': 2, 'left': 2})

    bottom_right_border = workbook.add_format({'bottom': 2, 'right': 2})

    table_title_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_color': 'white', 'bg_color': '#305496', 'align': 'left', 'valign': 'vcenter'})

    title_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_color': 'white', 'bg_color': 'black', 'align': 'left', 'valign': 'vcenter'})

    for j, df_part in enumerate(split_df):

      df_part.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheet_name + (("_"+ str(j)) if j > 0 else ""), index = False, header = False, startrow = 4, startcol = 1)

      worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name + (("_"+ str(j)) if j > 0 else "")]

      for col_num, value in enumerate(df_part.columns.values):

        worksheet.write(3,col_num+1,value,table_title_format)

      num_rows = df_part.shape[0]

      num_cols = df_part.shape[1]

      worksheet.conditional_format(3,2,3,num_cols-1,{"type": "no_errors", "format": top_border})

      worksheet.conditional_format(4,1,num_rows+2,1,{"type": "no_errors", "format": left_border})

      worksheet.conditional_format(4,num_cols,num_rows+2,num_cols,{"type": "no_errors", "format": right_border})

      worksheet.conditional_format(num_rows+3,2,num_rows+3,num_cols-1,{"type": "no_errors", "format": bottom_border})

      worksheet.conditional_format(3,1,3,1,{"type": "no_errors", "format": top_left_border})

      worksheet.conditional_format(3,num_cols,3,num_cols,{"type": "no_errors", "format": top_right_border})

      worksheet.conditional_format(num_rows+3,1,num_rows+3,1,{"type": "no_errors", "format": bottom_left_border})

      worksheet.conditional_format(num_rows+3,num_cols,num_rows+3,num_cols,{"type": "no_errors", "format": bottom_right_border})

      worksheet.hide_gridlines(2)

      worksheet.autofilter(3,1,num_rows+3,num_cols)

      worksheet.autofit()

      worksheet.set_column_pixels(0, 0, 20)

      worksheet.merge_range(1,1,1,num_cols, table_name + (("_"+ str(j)) if j > 0 else ""), title_format)

    workbook.close()

    shutil.copy(writer,output_path + file_name + ".xlsx")

    print(f"File {file_name}.xlsx created successfully")


I thought about several opportunities for optimisation but they didn't work out very well:

Performing all data processing using pyspark instead of pandas:
Wasn't feasible due to the requirement of formatting the Excel
workbook using xlsxwriter
Using an alternate library to xlsxwriter: I couldn't mimic the exact
functionality I have in this function
Parallel processing of the dataframes and avoiding storing them in
a list: Made my code harder to understand and I wasn't sure how to
properly leverage the spark cluster

If anyone has ideas or suggestions for how this function can be improved, I would gladly welcome them. Currently, the driver node gets overloaded and there is a spike in RAM usage because of pandas and xlsxwriter.

openpyxl and xlsxwriter are both used for pandas dataframes. You can use the spark plugin. But the spark plugin does not come in with formatting. For formatting you can look at using a excel template with the formatting setup. Then Copy this template and update the copy with the data.
You can install the library on the cluster level like so

Your code will look like this.
path = "abfss://<container_name>@<storage_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/testdir/test.xlsx"  

spark_Df1.write.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")\
  .option("header", "true")\
  .option("dataAddress", "'My Sheet1'!A1")\
  .mode("append")\
  .save(path)

The problem with xlsxwriter is that it can only write and not read/update.
So another option is to use the spark plugin to write the data and then use openpyxl to read and update the formatting. There is plenty of options on how to do this like THIS and THIS.
***Update
You can also try using multithreading in Python. You can find all the information on multithreading on python in this link.
Below is an example
First define a function to do your work.
import datetime as dt
def myfunc(col, dataframe, value):
    print(col, dt.datetime.now(), value)
    display(spark.sql(f"SELECT {col},COUNT(*) FROM source GROUP BY {col}")) 

Next call your function with parameters. Threadpool determines how many threads will be used.
%%time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(4)

cols_args = [('AGE',df,'TEST'),('SEX',df,'TEST'),('BMI',df,'TEST'),('BP',df,'TEST'),('S1',df,'TEST'),('S2',df,'TEST'),('S3',df,'TEST'),('S4',df,'TEST'),('S5',df,'TEST'),('S6',df,'TEST'),('Y',df,'TEST')]
opt2 = pool.starmap(myfunc,cols_args)

Basically read the csv as you are doing, but shift the actual writing of the excel to a function and pass the necessary parameters as a list. You can adjust the threadpool count to get your optimized performance. The above code has a value of 4.
Hopefully one of these options will improve the performance.

Just a small doubt. During my trials, I observed that writing any data to formatted cells erased all formatting, so the template presumably wouldn't work. I could try saving the file and reopening it to apply formatting, but I am worried that the memory efficiency would be identical to directly formatting and saving rather than saving and then formatting

Have you tried using multithreading ?

I would appreciate some pointers on using multithreading properly.
